# Soft proofing grayscale images in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-production, grayscale, proofing

When printing a grayscale image it's treated exactly like the black channel of a color image. So in order to get a correct preview of how it will look on print it must be soft proofed with the CMYK color profile the printer recommends.

InDesign does this by default. If I place a grayscale image in InDesign the image will be mapped to black ink by default. When I turn on *View > Proof Colors* set to the correct color profile, I get a realistic (and often slightly depressing) preview of how the image will look on print when printed with black ink:

[image]

If I open the grayscale image in Photoshop it's shown as if it were a neutral RGB image:

[image]

The darkest point is RGB(0, 0, 0) and the lightest point is RGB(255, 255, 255). So I can't trust that the image will look like this on print.

In Photoshop I can also turn on *View > Proof Colors* with the same settings as in InDesign, but then the image is shown as if it was *converted* to CMYK. It is slightly darker and (with this specific color profile) more neutral as it uses all four CMYK inks to create the image:

[image]

Photoshop doesn't seem to know that I want to see the grayscale images as it would look if printed in only black ink. Actually the preview looks exactly the same as it would with a neutral RGB image.

I can hack my way to get a proper preview in Photoshop if I create a CMYK image with the correct color profile and paste in the grayscale image in the black channel:

[image]

But that isn't a practical way to work for multiple reasons.

**Is there a way to properly soft proof grayscale images in Photoshop taking the ICC profile into account?**

Comment: Its a good question but its never going to have a satisfactory answer I think.

Comment: @joojaa, nah I guess so. Just weird there isn't a standardized way to edit grayscale images with soft proofing. Thought perhaps I was missing something obvious.

Comment: but how is photoshop to know that your not printing with a device that is not grayscale. Anyway the problem lies in the fact that you need to change your icc profile with a different  conversion. But the trick is you probably need to write it yourself as im not aware of any gui software to chain icc modules together in a GUI.